# How to redirect error stream to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following piece of code. I want to take the error stream, put it in variable after executing the command in the `for` loop, and in the meantime I discard the `stdout` by sending it to `NUL`.

```
 for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('%test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>NUL') do (
           set err_msg="%%~a"
    )
```

I wish to add one feature to it. In addition to sending `stdout` to `NUL` I want to store it in a file, how do I to add that functionality ?

Using the below code I can store the output to a file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('%test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>temp.txt') do (
           set err_msg="%%~a"    
)
```

But I want to store the output to a variable, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To store the first line only**:

```
set /p var=<temp.txt
```

Something like:

```
do (
    set err_msg="%%~a" && set /p var=<temp.txt
)
```

**To store multiple lines**:

To get multiple lines from `temp.txt` into a variable use DelayedExpansion and a second `for` loop:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (temp.txt) do set var=!var!%%x
```

---

Source [Set - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

> To place the first line of a file into a variable:
>
> ```
> Set /P _MyVar=<MyFilename.txt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To get std error to a variable, I created a FOR loop that redirects both std in and err to a findstr command which then lets you capture the text you are looking for.

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1-2 delims=" %a in ('*command* 2^>^&1^|findstr /I "*text*"') do (set x=%a)
```