# How to control flow of a batch file based on error name rather than error level?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, conda

I am writing my first batch file, and want to provide a conditional control flow based on the kind of error being output, rather than whether `%ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0`.

Specifically, I would like to create a conda environment that's cloned from a base environment, and if:

- the process fails because the base environment being cloned doesn't exist (`CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError`), create a new environment without cloning
- the process fails because the environment already exists (`CondaValueError`), skip the creation phase entirely

I think that would look something like this:

```
SET /p env_name="What would you like to call your environment? "

conda create --clone my-base-env --name %env_name%
IF %ERRORNAME% EQU CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError (
    ECHO Attempting to create a completely new environment
    conda create --name %env_name%
)
ELSE %ERRORNAME% EQU CondaValueError (
    :
)
```

What do I have to put in place of `%ERRORNAME%` in order for this conditional to work as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect error stream to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740883/how-to-redirect-error-stream-to-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about that `conda` thing, but I can help you with the batch-syntax:

```
SET /p env_name="What would you like to call your environment? "

conda create --clone my-base-env --name %env_name% 2>&1 |find "CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError" && ( 
    ECHO Attempting to create a completely new environment
    conda create --name %env_name%
) || (
  echo successfully created %env_name%
)
```

`2>&1` redirects `STDERR` to the same destination as `STDOUT` (because the following `find` command only processes `STDOUT`)
 `&&` works as "if previous command (`find`)  was successful, then"
`||` is the opposite: "if previous command (`find`) failed, then"
`find` looks for the string `CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError`in `STDOUT` and redirected `STDERR`