# How to capture image comparison result in Windows batch file, using ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I am trying to create a Windows bat file to compare two PDF files using GhostScript and ImageMagick 7.0.9 on Windows 10. First step creates PNG file for each page and magick.exe with "compare" command (there is no separate compare.exe on Windows) compares the images. Unfortunately the %errorlevel" remains 0 even when images do not match.

As a workaround I tried to use the output from magick compare which sends "0 (0)" to stderr on success. Here however I fail to capture the stderr into environment variable, possibly because of some variable scope issue or missing something else. The magick output is directed into temporary file and and then loaded with **set /P**. By adding pause after magick compare I can confirm that txt file contains "0 (0)" on matching files. echo %SCRIPTRESULT% prints nothing though.

```
set /P SCRIPTRESULT=<result/stdtmp.txt
```

The whole bat file:

```
@echo off
@rem we assume the current directory is root folder of the test that is being run
@rem get parameters
setlocal

set JOBNAME=%1
set FILETYPE=%2
set PAGECOUNT=%3
set PAGE=1
set FAILPAGE=1
set SCRIPTRESULT=

@rem create the PNG files for two PDFs in ./result/ and ./result_t/ folders

gswin64 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_CURR%%d.png -r200 ./result_t/%JOBNAME%.%FILETYPE%
gswin64 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_ORIG%%d.png -r200 ./result/%JOBNAME%.%FILETYPE%

@rem gs produces separate PNG for each PDF or PostScript page and we specify the expected count as parameter to this script

FOR /L %%P IN (1,1,%PAGECOUNT%) do (

  set PAGE=%%P
  rem echo Page %PAGE% of %PAGECOUNT%

  magick compare -metric MAE ./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_CURR%PAGE%.png ./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_ORIG%PAGE%.png ./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_DIFF%PAGE%.png 2> result/stdtmp.txt

  rem Errorlevel in Windows ImageMagick is always 0 so we need to observe sderr instead?
  echo The errorlevel is %errorlevel%

  set /P SCRIPTRESULT=<result/stdtmp.txt

  echo Compare returned %SCRIPTRESULT%

  del /Q .\result\stdtmp.txt
  del /Q ".\result\%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_CURR%PAGE%.png"
  del /Q ".\result\%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_ORIG%PAGE%.png"

  IF "%SCRIPTRESULT%" == "0 (0)" (
    echo Deleting .\result\%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_DIFF%PAGE%.png
    del /Q ".\result\%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_DIFF%PAGE%.png"
  ) ELSE (
    echo Failed at page %PAGE%
    set /A FAILPAGE=%PAGE%
  )
)

echo Outside the loop SCRIPTRESULT=%SCRIPTRESULT%

IF "%SCRIPTRESULT%" == "0 (0)" (
  echo Files compare OK  >&2
  )

IF NOT "%SCRIPTRESULT%" == "0 (0)" (
  echo Visual compare failed, see ./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_DIFF%FAILPAGE%.png >&2
)
```

One can run this script as

```
compare.bat filename pdf 1
```

This assumes we have .\result\filename.pdf and .\result_t\filename.pdf, each with 1 page. To complicate the matters further, this compare script is intendeded to be used by call from another script. In that case I see output:

```
The errorlevel is 0
Compare returned
Fail at page 1
Outside the loop SCRIPTRESULT=0 (0)
Files compare OK
```

So apparently the value of SCRIPTRESULT outside the loop is "0 (0)" as expected, but not inside the FOR loop? Adding **setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** did not have any apparent effect.

Comment: You can capture stderr to a variable using the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740883/how-to-redirect-error-stream-to-variable

Comment: You need delayed variable expansion to use the changed value of a variable inside a code block.  Inside the for loop you need to use `!SCRIPTRESULT!` instead of `%SCRIPTRESULT%`.

Comment: You also need `!PAGE!` or you will only ever be comparing page 1 no matter the pagecount.  Though you can just use `%%P` instead.

Comment: Oh right -- the same thing for `%ERRORLEVEL%`.  You can see if `!ERRORLEVEL!` works, or just use the builtin `if errorlevel 1` logic.

Comment: Rather than reading in the contents of `stdtmp.txt`, maybe you could just use `FINDSTR` to see if it has what you want...

Comment: @avery_larry Perfect, I did not even know there is this exclamation mark construct. And indeed - the errorlevel actually changes to 1 but % was simply hiding it from me. All this would make an acceptable answer btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting functioning version of script, thanks to the commenters. Assuming there are two single-page PDF files .\result\some.pdf and .\result_t\some.pdf, run the compare:

```
compare.bat some pdf 1
```

It will also work with PostScript or anything else that GhostScript can render. Failed match will leave a visual difference file in the 'result' folder.

```
@rem we assume the current directory is root folder of the test that is being run
@echo off
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set JOBNAME=%1
set FILETYPE=%2
set PAGECOUNT=%3
set FAILPAGE=0

@rem Using either pngalpha or png16m device

gswin64 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_CURR%%d.png -r200 ./result_t/%JOBNAME%.%FILETYPE%
gswin64 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_ORIG%%d.png -r200 ./result/%JOBNAME%.%FILETYPE%

@rem gs produces separate PNG for each PDF or PostScript page and we specify the expected count as parameter to this script
@rem Note that we do not catch case where the result has more pages than template

FOR /L %%P IN (1,1,%PAGECOUNT%) do (

  magick compare -metric MAE "./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_CURR%%P.png" "./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_ORIG%%P.png" "./result/%JOBNAME%_%FILETYPE%_DIFF%%P.png" 2>nul

  rem echo The errorlevel is !errorlevel!

  IF !errorlevel! == 0 (
    del /Q ".\result\%JOBNAME%_!FILETYPE!_DIFF%%P.png"
  ) ELSE (
    echo Difference on page %%P
    set /A FAILPAGE=%%P
  )

  del /Q ".\result\%JOBNAME%_!FILETYPE!_CURR%%P.png"
  del /Q ".\result\%JOBNAME%_!FILETYPE!_ORIG%%P.png"
)

IF  !FAILPAGE! == 0 (
  echo Files compare OK >&2
  EXIT /B 0
  ) else (
  echo Visual compare failed, see ./result/%JOBNAME%_!FILETYPE!_DIFF!FAILPAGE!.png >&2
  EXIT /B 1
)
```